# Table lookups of Powers of 10

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm working on a C++ project in which computation speed is of utmost importance.  Any time that I can cut, should be cut.  The final size of the executable and the memory usage is not *as* important.

That being said, will it be beneficial to create a pre-computed lookup table of the powers of 10?  For example, if I were to have this simplified function:

```
double powTen(int exponent) {
    return pow(10, exponent);
}
```

Would it have a (small) increase in performance if I replaced the `pow()` with a table lookup?  Is it even worth it?  It seems as though the `pow()` function must be fairly complex.  Also, does GCC have a special optimization for this?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. You should profile your code first to see if this is a real bottleneck.

Comment: Table lookup is nearly always nice for performance. So *assuming you have identified this as a bottleneck* I'd use the (expected to be short) time on implementing a template that generates the table. Do **measure**, however. Performance is a strange beast on modern computers. It can go in directions one never would believe.

Comment: Only thing you can do is try it. It seems like a valid thing to do and would certainly help if you knew that your function was called a lot (if its not why bother). Also it will realistically have quite a narrow set of inputs, so is simple to unit test and once it's done you can reuse it in other projects with high confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table lookup is nearly always nice for performance. So assuming you have identified this as a bottleneck I'd use the time on implementing a template that generates the table. Do measure, however. Performance is a strange beast on modern computers. It can go in directions one never would believe.

I expected the time to implement compile time table generation to be very short indeed. But it turned out that Visual C++ 2015, at least as of old update 2, is not happy at all with a `constexpr std::array` in a class. However, at the end, a raw array worked.

Code, compiled with MinGW g++ 6.3.0 and Visual C++ 2015 update 2:

```
#include <stddef.h>     // size_t, ptrdiff_t
#include <utility>      // std::(make_index_sequence, )

namespace my {
    using std::make_index_sequence;
    using std::index_sequence;

    using Size = ptrdiff_t;

    template< Size n, class Item >
    using raw_array_of_ = Item[n];

    template< class Item, size_t n >
    constexpr
    auto n_items_of( raw_array_of_<n, Item>& )
        -> Size
    { return n; }

    namespace impl {
        constexpr
        auto compile_time_pow_of_10( int const n )
            -> double
        { return (n == 0? 1.0 : 10.0*compile_time_pow_of_10( n - 1 )); }

        template< size_t... indices >
        struct Powers_of_10_
        {
            static constexpr size_t                     n       = sizeof...(indices);
            static constexpr raw_array_of_<n, double>   table   =
            {
                compile_time_pow_of_10( indices )...
            };

            constexpr
            Powers_of_10_() {}
        };

        template< size_t... indices >
        constexpr
        raw_array_of_<Powers_of_10_<indices...>::n, double>
            Powers_of_10_<indices...>::table;

        template< size_t... indices, int n = sizeof...(indices) >
        constexpr
        auto power_of_10_table_helper( index_sequence<indices...> )
            -> const raw_array_of_<n, double>&
        { return Powers_of_10_<indices...>::table; }
    }  // namespace impl

    template< int n >
    constexpr
    auto power_of_10_table()
        -> const raw_array_of_<n, double>&
    { return impl::power_of_10_table_helper( make_index_sequence<n>() ); }

}  // namespace my

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main()
    -> int
{
    int const n = 7;
    constexpr auto& pow_10 = my::power_of_10_table<n>();

    cout << n << " powers of 10:\n";
    cout << fixed;  cout.precision( 0 );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        cout << pow_10[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Template code can be difficult to port. To wit: Visual C++ 2015's refusal to accept `std::array` in the above code, necessitating a rewrite to use raw array instead. It's also difficult to maintain, due to the usually overly long and cryptic compilation diagnostics.

A reasonably fast integral power function can be defined by expressing the power as a product of powers of the form *x*<sup>(2<sup>*n*</sup>)</sup>. For example, *x*<sup>42</sup> = *x*<sup>32</sup>⋅*x*<sup>8</sup>⋅*x*<sup>2</sup>, and these more basic powers of *x*, namely 2, 8, and 32, can be computed by repeatedly squaring *x*. This reduces the number of multiplications from linear in the exponent, to logarithmic in the exponent.

Code:

```
#include <stddef.h>     // size_t, ptrdiff_t

namespace my {
    using Size = ptrdiff_t;

    template< Size n, class Item >
    using raw_array_of_ = Item[n];

    namespace impl {
        auto positive_integral_power_of( const double x, const int n )
        {
            double result = 1.0;
            double power = x;
            for( unsigned exp = n; ; )
            {
                if( (exp & 1) != 0 )
                {
                    result *= power;
                }
                exp >>= 1;
                if( exp == 0 )
                {
                    break;
                }
                power *= power;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }  // namespace impl

    auto integral_power_of( const double x, const int n )
        -> double
    {
        return
            n > 0? 
                impl::positive_integral_power_of( x, n ) :
            n < 0?
                1.0 / impl::positive_integral_power_of( x, -n ) :
            1.0;
    }
}  // namespace my

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main()
    -> int
{
    int const n = 7;
    cout << n << " powers of 10:\n";
    cout << fixed;  cout.precision( 0 );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        cout << my::integral_power_of( 10, i ) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough response, sir! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to show upvotes :).  Could you explain why you used `auto functionName() -> returnType` instead of something like `returnType functionName()`?

Comment: @hello: I use the trailing return type syntax as a single function declaration syntax. Why use the old syntax in addition? It's much more limited.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the function a little bit more efficient by using a loop:

```
double powerTen(int exponent)
{
  double result = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < exponent; ++i)
  {
    result = result * 10.0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

A benefit of the loop is that you are removing the function call overhead to `pow` function.  Not much of a savings, IMO.

An alternative is the table lookup:

```
double powerTen(int exponent)
{
  static const double values[] = {1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0};
  return values[exponent];
}
```

You are trading memory space for execution time.
Also you may want to add in some array overflow checks as well as handling negative exponents.

Comment: In the middle here is the optimization of the loop you show, by e.g. computing x^4 as x2 = x*x; x4 = x2*x2. A general implementation of that can use the binary representation of the exponent to decide how to compute the powers. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  I was considering adding loop unrolling to the first example, but the issue of space vs. efficiency kept debating in my head.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of using a loop to eliminate function call overhead.  With loop unrolling, my understanding is that there is a slight performance gain but it takes more space, correct?  Also, I noticed you declared `static const double values[]` inside of the `powerTen()` function.  Noob question: does this re-declare the `values[]` constant each time this function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Do you call this function that much ? If so then pre-computation of expected values will be better.

You can also use partially built table and build with usage, ie. first time 10^5 called calculate it, then save in table so next time it would be got from table.

Using table is always better than calling a function, but the thing is it has to worth it first, by calling many times, or sending the same params many times, so that you dont end up with calling the function at first big time, and then not use at all, which would ruin your first intention of optimizing at the tiniest bit.